# Validate subdocuments in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I am using a Schema as a Subdocument in Mongoose, but I am not able to validate it in its fields.
That's what I have

```
var SubdocumentSchema = new Schema({
    foo: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    bar: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    }
});

var MainDocumentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  children: {
    type : [ SubdocumentSchema.schema ],
    validate: arrayFieldsCannotBeBlankValidation
  }
});
```

I want to be sure that every field of the subdocument is not empty.
I found out that this is not possible to validate an Array with standard methods, so I wrote my custom validation function.
By now I have to manually check that all the fields are correct and not empty, but it looks to me like a not really scalable solution, so I was wondering if there was some native method to trigger the Subdocument validation from the MainDocument one.

Comment: I am happy to see your validate function `arrayFieldsCannotBeBlankValidation` Is it going to validate each object in the array? ex: is it going to check any duplicate values with `MainDocumentSchema.children.name` ?

Comment: I honestly don't remember, the code has gone long time ago. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the definition of `children`, it should be `[SubdocumentSchema]`, not `[SubdocumentSchema.schema]`:

```
var MainDocumentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  children: {
    type : [ SubdocumentSchema ],
    validate: arrayFieldsCannotBeBlankValidation
  }
});
```

`SubdocumentSchema.schema` evaluates to `undefined` so in your current code Mongoose doesn't have the necessary type information to validate the elements of `children`.

Comment: Thanks man. I was messing up everything trying to run a custom validation on the array thinking the problem was there, while it was in the way I was invoking the schema. You saved me.